# Handle UploadedFile in csv.reader

Tags: django

I am trying to read an uploaded file without saving it:

```
def import_file(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UploadForm()
    else:
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            rdr = csv.reader(request.FILES["file"], delimiter=',')
            for row in rdr:
                print(row)
                ...
```

But I get `iterator should return strings, not bytes (the file should be opened in text mode)` If i was reading a file with `open` function, I could have opened it with `'rt'`. But in this case I am dealing with `TemporaryUploadedFile` class if I'm not mistaken. So I can't re-open it. What is the correct aproach here? Based on simpilar topics I've tried using `read()` and `decode("UTF-8")` and `decode("ISO-8859-1")` on the `TemporaryUploadedFile`, but so far nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode your content before passing to `reader(...)`

```
def import_file(request):
    stream = request.FILES["file"].read().decode("utf-8").splitlines()
    rdr = csv.reader(stream, delimiter=',')
    for row in rdr:
        print(row)
        ...
```

Comment: ```splitlines()``` is what I was missing, thanks